# SQL join, sum, group-by and instead of null 0

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum

I need a query with posts-id, posts-title, posts-created_at, users-name and likes-status. likes-status should be 0 if none exists. And i need the sum of likes-status. Like this:

```
id |title   |created_at |name  |status  |
=========================================
1  |Hello 1 |2015-07-22 |Baker |0       |    // 1 - 1
2  |Hallo 2 |2015-07-23 |Tom   |0       |    // if not exists = 0
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.created_at, u.name, IFNULL(l.status, 0) as status
FROM posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id
```

Result:

```
id |title   |created_at |name  |status  |
=========================================
1  |Hello 1 |2015-07-22 |Baker |1       |    // sum this
1  |Hello 1 |2015-07-22 |Baker |-1      |    // with this
2  |Hallo 2 |2015-07-23 |Tom   |0       |
```

users table

```
id |name  |email             |password |created_at |
====================================================
1  |Baker |baker@example.com |UHds(&   |2015-07-20 |
2  |Tom   |tom@example.com   |ihj=)?   |2015-07-21 |
```

posts table

```
id |user_id |title   |created_at |
==================================
1  |1       |Hello 1 |2015-07-22 |
2  |2       |Hello 2 |2015-07-23 |
```

likes table

```
id |user_id |post_id |status |created_at  |
===========================================
1  |1       |1       |1      |2015-07-24  |
2  |2       |1       |-1     |2015-07-25  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start a query with `left join`, then you should to continue it.  This doesn't actually affect your query, which needs a `group by`, but it is still a good idea:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.created_at, u.name, COALESCE(sum(l.status), 0) as status
FROM posts p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     likes l
     ON l.post_id = p.id LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     users u
     ON u.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.created_at, u.name;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had an error. The status column was a typ of enum with 1 and -1. I got always 3 instead of 0 for 1 - 1.